# How to get gmail password when login through google Account id in android

Tags: android, google-api

Using this code,it does not return a gmail password on login by Gmail,want to get password on login,help this code:

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches())
 {
            passWord = AccountManager.get(this).getPassword(account) ; 
}
}
```

Comment: Very illegal...well, you cant get it at all

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the password by code, as its restricted.